# How can I split a Windows 7 image on to multiple CDRs that I can boot from to install?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

Is there a way that I can do this? I'd appreciate any help / pointers.

Comment: good question, i doubt that someone will come up with something. but why do you want to do this? usbsticks works well ...

Comment: @Akira: In the past I have had a computer that met the requirements for Windows 7 (except a DVD drive), yet didn't boot from USB. Then again, I would have just popped in a DVD drive for the installation itself.

Comment: How about this solution instead: http://superuser.com/questions/42263/how-to-install-windows-7-from-the-network

Comment: Did it not boot from USB because the computer doesn't support it or because perhaps the USB wasn't setup to be boot from properly? Give this a go http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/ I have used it a few times, normally to deploy our WDS images offsite, but should work in your case (if you computer does support usb boot and just needs a properly configured flash drive).

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like [Plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html#intro)? You could make a bootable USB flash drive with Windows 7 on it and boot from Plop, which could then allow you to boot from the flash drive.

edit: I realize this isn't exactly the question you're asking, but it might work for the situation you're in...

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Automated Installation Kit (AIK) includes a utility called imagex, which will split a .wim image, among other things. The AIK is really the way to go for building customized Windows installations.