# PXE boot issue: Macrium Linux, Atheros NIC, ASUS motherboard

Tags: boot, pxe, network-adapter, macrium

The problem is mainly with the NIC, I suspect: Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114

I've got a PXE boot environment running from a TFTP/DHCP server (as documented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/42263/how-to-install-Windows-7-from-the-network/265214#265214)).  The server points to a boot file in the "Macrium Reflect Rescue CD" Linux kernel using PXELINUX.  Then the client runs the "Rescue" GUI over the network.

It ran fine on a different machine (with a Realtek NIC).

However, on this new machine, the kernel boots, the GUI loads, but then the "Network Share" doesn't work.  I click 'Network Settings' and there's no IPV4 info assigned/retrieved.

I suspect this is because a driver is not loaded for the card?  Can someone help out?

Comment: did you try using the 'alternate' cd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the Linux kernel doesn't have a driver for your NIC. You could try

```
modprobe atl1e
```

(as root, or with `sudo`) in a console to see if the driver can be manually loaded.

The driver should be available in many other distros, so if this doesn't help maybe you could just try a different boot image.