# How I can install Windows 8 over network?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, pxe

I have tried to use Tftpd32 but it did not work. I think because it asks for `pxesomething.com` which I don't have.

Comment: What was the exact reason it didn't work?  Please be specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Windows 7 from the network?](http://superuser.com/questions/42263/how-to-install-windows-7-from-the-network)

Comment: @Ramhound, there is no `pxeboot.com` file under `boot` folder.

Comment: @ilhan - Update your question with the information instead of adding a comment.