# Quick way to install win7 and programs on many new 'OSless' miniPCs that will be connected in local network

Tags: windows-7, networking, iso-image, disk-image

is there a quick way to install win7 and some basic programs (skype, and few others) on many (exact same manufacture) new 'OSless' miniPCs that will be connected in local network.
I know I can create a bootable usb and place inside it a win7 installer, but I was wondering if somehow I can make an image of a win7 (configured with all my basic programs) and then mount that image on each new OSless PC, is that possible? what about if there are meant to be connected in a local network? Isn't there any shortcut that could spare me having to install win7, config it, install programs, on every single PC?? Thanks Advanced.

PD: I'm familiar with AOEMI Backupper (currently using it to backup-restore windows system), I know it can clone a disk to another, but you have to plug every 'destination' disk into the PC where the 'source' disk is placed in order to perform the cloning. I would like to somehow mount an image of my OS into a bootable USB, and install that image on every PC. is that possible? Could please somebody provide some tutorial link fo how to do it?? Thanks Advanced.

could someone please tell me what is the difference between a normal installation of windows7 and a Windows PE installation? I have read here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx that they are different. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: You could use something like Norton Ghost to create an image of a complete install, then write that image to the rest of your PCs. We've used an HDD duplicator in the past to also achieve a similar result.

Comment: Hi @MichaelFrank how could I write an image on a PC that has any OS installed? Do I use some kind of bootable image???? what about the PC name and other configs, does it make troubles when connecting all PCs in a local network??

Comment: Depending on the method, you normally just use a bootable environment to apply the image. As for config? You can create a generic build and rename the PC after it has been imaged.

Comment: what is the format of the Norton Ghost image? does that image can be uploaded from a usb drive in a OSless PC??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options

1. Make a disk image with everything you need, install it on a few USBs and go around installing onto all machines.
2. Use a PXE to boot off an image on the LAN and install that way
3. Install generic windows then run Ninite to install any apps you want. https://ninite.com/

Comment: Hi @Linef4ult. what softwares I can use to do option 1, I mean, what softwares make a disk image? can I use AOEMI backupper for that? please could you mention one software or link?. If I go for option 2, Can I install my image on many PCs on the LAN at same time using PXE? again what software do you suggest for doing that? do you have any tutorial link? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Hi @Linef4ult but Im worried about the PXE 'Windows PE' way, cuz It says here technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx ...that "Windows PE automatically stops running the shell and reboots after 72 hours of continuous use. This time period is not configurable". Isn't there any other way to install on all machines through LAN???? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: WinPE isnt related to LAN booting. For 1 try here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825131.aspx For 2. This guide covers it all. Theres a bit of setup but then its really quick to do on each machine. http://www.7tutorials.com/how-install-any-version-windows-other-network-computers

Comment: Hi @Linef4ult can the way 2 mount an image of windows8 (configurated with a few installed programs)??? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: @Natysiu16 Yep. Basically it acts like a boot CD but over ethernet, so any bootable disk image should work. Win7, win8, w10, ubuntu and so on. What size is your deployment (how many units)?

Comment: Hi @Linef4ult thanks, So now you clarify that I can mount a fully operational OS with its programs already installed through PXE, I would like to mount that OS image on 10 PCs at same time. Please could you tell me if I can do it using AOMEI tool show in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_rrG6sNO0M (since I'm already familiar with AOMEI Backupper) the video shows how use the AOMEI PXE Boot Tool, please could you tell me if this is possible? if not, could you tell me which software could do such task? what about Norton Ghost? which has more tutos online? could you post a link?THanks.

Comment: You *could*, but it would be "live" booting, that is to say it wouldnt persist and would have to boot slowly off the PXE host every time its turned on. Not what you really want. You should use PXE to get the installation going, then install the preconfigured image onto each machine, then set it to boot from its own HDD from then on. No experience with that tool.

Comment: Hi @Linef4ult yes that exactly what Im want to do, use the PXE to get the installation going, so the PCs can bot from its own HDD from then on. but I didn't understand, do I have to mount the image on each PC, one by one?? what software could I use to do so?? Do you have some link??? thanks Advanced. Please take into account that they are new OSless PCs. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: @Natysiu16 Ah, theres one bit you've missed. The BIOS does the PXE part. This video gives you an idea https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDnWtCUbRyI Basically once youve setup the boot server you turn on a "new" machine, hit ESC/F11/F12, select PXE or LAN boot and away you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a net install (PXE) with Microsoft WDS/MDT/SCCM but if you want something far easier you can also try [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) where you can use a regular Windows 7 DVD with a customized **Install.wim** to suit your needs. (I'm related to Serva development)

Comment: Hi @Pat I've seen this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lOISNGWTo4 video about installing Windows7 using symantec ghost, do you please have some link tutorial of how to do it with Serva? Can I install my image on many PCs on the LAN at same time using PXE? if possible can I do it with Serva Non-Suppoter? Thanks Advance

Comment: Creating a customized image for Serva install it is as easy as to customize your Windows 7 DVD `Intstall.wim` file with `dism.exe`. With dism you can add to Install.wim whatever you want i.e. drivers, applications, etc. Serva also supports unattended installs (not user interaction). With Serva non-supporter (free) you can install your image on many PCs but only 2 at the time; also you cannot use the free version on a commercial environment.

Comment: Hi @Pat, what about this method??is that more difficult? http://superuser.com/questions/42263/how-to-install-windows-7-from-the-network, and what about CCbot?? Could you please tell me the difference between those methods and Serva?? and what is that Microsoft WDS/MDT/SCCM method?? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Your first link forces you to  manually do what Serva automates plus the TFTP server used (tftpd32) without `windowsize` support will lead to very slow/error prone `Boot.wim` transfers. CCboot is more for iSCSI based live systems, not what you are trying to do. Microsoft has 3 bundles that deal with your problem; WDS, MDT, and SCCM; WDS and MDT are free SCCM is not; they are not really easy to learn.

Comment: Thanks @Pat could you please tell me if the Serva solution is based on Windows PE??, what about norton ghost PXE, or AOEMI backupper PXE boot tool, I know that AOEMI PXE boot tool is based on Windows PE, could you please tell me what is the difference between a normal installation of windows7 and a Windows PE installation? I have read here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx that they are different. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: all the installations of Windows Vista and up implemented by Serva are PE based. Serva installs exactly as Microsoft RIS and WDS do. Ghost is a different thing they have 2 different kinds of clients; one of them is PE based but they do not implement the MS WDS style; they just install their own images.  AOEMI PXE is a Chinese option that just make no much sense to me.

Comment: Hi @Pat, thanks for your support, but Im worried about the 'Windows PE' way, cuz It says here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx ...that "Windows PE automatically stops running the shell and reboots after 72 hours of continuous use. This time period is not configurable". Is this the case when using Serva, right? could you please point me which way I should use instead of Windows PE to make a network boot installation of windows7 so those PCs can be used 24/7? thanks Advanced.

Comment: PD: could you please tell me if Serva can install an image of a Windows7 that has some programs already installed onto it? or it only installs windows7 alone. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: PE is only used during the install process; then you do not have to worry about the 72 hours time-out and Yes; Serva can install a customized image of Windows7. I hope you'll understand we cannot continue this conversation here. Please close the question taking the best answer. Bye

Comment: FOrgive me @Pat but I don't get it, why it say here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx that windows PE installation has its limitations??? So you mean, I will got a fully operational customized image of Windows7, as if I would have clone my hard drive where my OS is placed?? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: PE limitations are not observable when PE is used as a boot/install tool; that's it. PE shows limitations if you want to use it as a regular OS. Yes you can customize `Install.wim` as you please and deploy it with Serva. That does not mean `cloning` your hard disk you are mixing concepts there. Sorry this is just too long.

Answer (score 1):

I'd install everything, then boot a Linux, and do:
`dd if=/dev/sdX of=~/harddrive_backup.iso`
replace sdX with the drive. You can list them with lsblk.

This is the most general way as it will copy the *whole* drive, not only one partition but the whole drive with MBR etc.
Depending on how it's set up you can optimize but this is working fine.

Then just use:
`dd if=~/harddrive_backup.iso of=/dev.sdX`
to get it onto another drive. It should be able to do that with PXE boot, too. Quite easily actually.